# Get number of same values in arrays in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I need a function `int countDifferentNumbers(int v[], int n)` which counts how many different values the array `v` with `n` entries contains.

**Example:**

It should return the result 3 for the array `v = {1, 5, 5, 8, 1, 1}` because the array contains only `3` different values.

**This is how the code looks like so far:**

```
int countDifferentNumbers(int v[], int n)
{
    int counter = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        for(int j = i; j < n; ++j)
        {
            if(v[i] == v[j + 1])
            {
                cout << "match" << endl;
                counter++;
                cout << v[i] << endl;
            }
        }
    }
    
    return counter;
}
```

I would appreciate an explanation of what is wrong in my function and how I need to redesign it.

*Note: Unfortunately, I have not found a suitable thread for this either. All threads with my problems were solved in Java and Python languages.*

Comment: Your function counts numbers that are the same not different. Plus `j+1` is outside the bounds of the array at the end of the inner loop.

Comment: What you need is a better algorithm. Take the first number in the array, remove from the array all numbers that are the same as that number (including itself). Repeat this process for the new first number in the array. Keep repeating until the array is empty. The number of times you repeat this process is the number of unique numbers in the array. Not the most efficient algorithm but it works.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Please reconsider your comment, it could easily be understood as "What did you not understand in your text book?" Which, I hope you agree, is neither what you mean nor helpful.

Comment: This function could be implemented with one line: `return std::set<int>(v, v+n).size();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recently I see more and more answers here on SO that lead users in the wrong direction by giving bad answers.

Also, for C++, the question has already been answered in the comment by Igor Tandetnik, and that should finally be used.

But let me answer the question of the OP as asked. What is wrong with my function? OK, there are several aspects. Let us first look at the style.

You have 0 lines of comments, so the code quality is 0. If you would write comments, then you would already find most bugs by yourself, because then, you need to explain your own wrong statements.

Then please see your source code with my amendments. I added the problems as comment.

```
// This is just a dumped function and not a minimum reproducible example
// All header files are messing
// Obviously "using namespace std;" was used that should NEVER be done

// The function should retrun an unsigned value, best size_t, because a count can never be negative
// Same for n, that is the size of an array. Can also never be negative
// C-sytle arrays should NEVER be used in C++. NEVER. Use std::vector or std::array instead
int countDifferentNumbers(int v[], int n)
{
    int counter = 0;    // Now in C++ we can use braced initialzation instead of assignement
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) 
    {
        for (int j = i; j < n; ++j)
        {
            if (v[i] == v[j + 1])  // Accessing out of bounds element
            {
                cout << "match" << endl; // Now endl needed here. Can all be done in one cout statement in one line
                counter++;  // Always counting up the same counter for all kind of double numbers.
                cout << v[i] << endl;
            }
        }
    }
    return counter;
```

That was one point of the answer. But now the second point. Evene more important. The algorithm or the design is wrong. And finding the correct solution, this thinking before codingt, you need to do, before you write any line of code.

You obviously want to find the count of unique numbers in an array.

Then you could look what is already there on Stackoverflow. You would probaly find 20 answers already that coud give you a hint.

You could use `std::unique`. Please see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique) for a description. This function sounds like it does what you want, right? Some example implementation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

// If you want to keep the original data, remove the reference-specifier &
size_t countDifferentNumbers(std::vector<int>& v) {
    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());                      // Sorting is precondition for std::unique
    v.erase(std::unique(v.begin(), v.end()), v.end());  // Erase all non-unique elements
    return v.size(); // Return the result
}

int main() {
    std::vector test{ 1, 5, 5, 8, 1, 1 };               // Some test data
    std::cout << countDifferentNumbers(test) << '\n';   // SHow result to user
    return 0;
}
```

Then, we could count the occurence of each number in a `std::map` or `std::unordered_map`. And the number of counters will be the result. Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

// If you want to keep the original data, remove the reference-specifier &
size_t countDifferentNumbers(std::vector<int>& v) {

    std::unordered_map<int, size_t> counter{};          // Here we will count all occurences of different numbers
    for (const int i : v) counter[i]++;                 // Iterate over vector and count different numbers
    return counter.size();                              // Count of different numbers
}

int main() {
    std::vector test{ 1, 5, 5, 8, 1, 1 };               // Some test data
    std::cout << countDifferentNumbers(test) << '\n';   // Show result to user
    return 0;
}
```

But, then, thinking further, about what conatiners we could use, we will find out the answer from Igor Tandetnik. There are 2 containers that can hold unique values only. No double values. And these are: `std::set` and `std::unordered_set`., So, we can simply copy the data into one of those containers, and, only unique values will be stored there.

There are many ways to get the data into a set. But the simplest one is to use its range constructor. Then, we have unique elements, and, the containers `size` function will give the result:

See here: [Constructor Number 2](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/unordered_set).

The result will be a function with one line like this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <vector>

// If you want to keep the original data, remove the reference-specifier &
size_t countDifferentNumbers(std::vector<int>& v) {

    return std::unordered_set<int>(v.begin(), v.end()).size();
}

int main() {
    std::vector test{ 1, 5, 5, 8, 1, 1 };               // Some test data
    std::cout << countDifferentNumbers(test) << '\n';   // Show result to user
    return 0;
}
```

And since functions with one line are often not so usefull, we can also write the final solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector test{ 1, 5, 5, 8, 1, 1 };                                           // Some test data
    std::cout << std::unordered_set<int>(test.begin(), test.end()).size() << '\n';  // Show result to user
    return 0;
}
```

So, by analyzing the problem and choosing the right algorithm and container and using C++, we come to the most easy solution.

---

Please enable C++17 for your compiler.

Answer (score 1):

first sort the array `v`. if `n >0` then initially there must be one number which is unique so just increment the value of `counter` once.  then with loop check if the two consecutive number are same or not. if same do nothing else increment the value of `counter`.

if you are writing code in c then use qsort. `#include <stdlib.h>` add this in header and. use `qsort()` func

here is the code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int countDifferentNumbers(int v[] , int n)
{
   
    int counter = 0;
    sort(v, v+ n);  // if you are writing code in c then just write  a decent sort algorithm. 
    
    if (n>0 ){
         printf("%d\n", v[0]);
        counter ++;
    }
    
    for(int i = 0; i < n-1; ++i)
    {
       if(v[i] == v[i+1]){
           continue;
       } else {
           printf("%d\n", v[i+1]);
           counter++;
       }
    }
    
    return counter;
}

int main()
{
    
    int v[] = {1, 5, 5, 8, 1, 1};
    int result = countDifferentNumbers(v,6);
    printf("unique number %d", result );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: For the record, in C there's [`qsort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort)

Comment: @IgorTandetnik  thanks i have updated my ans with c also

Comment: Do not  write answers which explain things to the OP that he should NOT do. The question is tagged with C++. Why a C answer? You should NEVER use ````#include <bits/stdc++.h> or using namespace std;````. You shopuld not use C-Style arrays, and decayed pointers. Use ````std::vector````. Use unsigned data types (like ````size_t````) for counters. Never use printf in C++. Read the comments. The C++ solution is given by  Igor Tandetnik. This is a typical one liner: ````return std::set<int>(v, v+n).size();```` Why writing so many useless lines of code? How can there be an upvote? Why accepted?